# How to preserve vibrancy after inverted overlay correction?

Tags: gimp

I'm sometimes using a trick to bring out darker areas:

- Duplicate layer.
- Colours -> Invert.
- Set mode to "Overlay" for the new layer, play with opacity for it.

But sometimes this results in quite vibrant lighter areas becoming "washed out".

For example in this:

[image: Original]

The quite nice background becomes a bit washed out:
[image: After overlay]

I tried playing with curves, levels and other tools on both layers, but couldn't preserve background vibrancy while lightening up the darker foreground.

Is there a reasonably simple method to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your invert-overlay trick may work in some cases, but it doesn't know what is the actual problem area, so as well you can use some other as dumb, but probably more flexible process and then limit its area to the wanted parts with a layer mask.

Photoshop and Krita users would add a curves adjustment layer and limit the effect with a layer mask, but in GIMP there's no adjustment layers, you must duplicate the original image layer to have it available in case you make an error.

So, duplicate the image layer and apply curves so that the foreground items look acceptable. The rest of the image becomes washed, but let it be:

[image]

Insert a layer mask. Let at first the mask be the original image inverted. Make the mask better by applying curves and by painting black and white to it. It's tried in the next image. Sorry for using Photoshop, but the same can be done in GIMP with no problems:

[image]

This maybe is too aggressive on the feet - there's a shadow on the ground and it should affect also the shoes. Paint to the mask with a soft low opacity brush some black on too bright areas. The shoes are fixed in the next image:

[image]

Another way to get the mask is to make a selection and  convert it to a layer mask. It can as well be tuned by painting, if needed. This method is also fast in cases where the foreground items have sharp edges.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a different technique.  Try this instead.

1. Do *Colors > Shadows-Highlights*
2. Move the radius slider towards the left
3. Move the shadows slider towards the right

Toggle the preview on/off to see the difference, or use the split view option. Tweak as you like.

An example

[image]

Before and after split view

[image]